# Load data in app

Tags: java, android, database, performance

We have an app about some exams related stuff and we got stuck on how to load the app with questions as questions containing images and sometime only text.

So my question is what data structure we should use to load app content on first run, whether we should read form file or place images in folder but then how the mapping is achieved in question with its image?

one more thing app is having local database which is storing all the stuff, actually my question is how to populate database, in what structure the questions to be provided so that updation will not be difficult?

Comment: DB in Android is SQLite. http://www.sqlite.org/

Comment: yes i know DB in android is SQLite but my problem is to populate that database with data at first run and how the format of that data should be json, some files, excel or anything because images are also there?

Comment: This is about your development skills, your choices. You can first read data then save it into SQLite. I would choose to read from JSON if possible. You should give path for your images and save them into SQLite with your questions. You should put your images under the assets file. Because you should read them with their names.

Comment: thanks akguncse, i posted this question to know views of others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it with sqlite or xml file in either ways put your images in a folder and store the path to the images have a flag which indicates it contains text or image based on the flag fetch the column with text or image path